# route regex check if id exists in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When you want to only accept a specific parameter for a route you do this:

```
Route::get('users/{id}', 'UsersController@show')->where('id', '\d+');
```

But what if I want something like:

```
Route::get('users/{id}', 'UsersController@show')->where('id', '\d+')->where(this id exists in table column id);
```

How is this possible with laravel?
I want to return page not found if the id doesn't exist in the db yet.

---

**update**

I had an idea to create a filter:

```
Route::filter('user.exists', function()
{
//get the id then check the database
});
```

But how do I pass an $id to the filter?

---

*note*

I know that I can do something like check if the query returned any data in the controller and throw 404 if now like:

```
$user = User::find($id);

if(!$user){
    App::abort(404);
}
```

But I think it would be cleaner if I can do this in the route itself. Because I have more to filter not only the users.

Answer (score 1):

This should help get you started:

```
Route::get('users/{id}', 'UsersController@show', array('before' => 'userExists'))->where('id', '[\d]+');

Route::filter('userExists', function($id) {
  echo $id; exit;
});
```